# Duplicar una hoja de excel con openpyxl en python

Tags: python-3.x, excel

Quisiera duplicar una hoja de `excel`, en decir copiar toda la hoja no solo los datos, estoy usando `openpyxl` pero no he encontrado una opción para duplicar un `worksheet`.

```
sheet = workbook[hoja]

libro2 = "prueba5.xlsx"
workbook2 = openyxl.load_workbook(libro2)
hoja3 = "Hoja15.xlsx"
sheet3 = workbook2[hoja3]

#workbook2.create sheet(sheet["B" + str(fila)].value)
```

En este caso quisiera duplicar `sheet3` en el mismo documento, cualquier ayuda lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Bienvenido @Arnold Valencia a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Copiar o duplica en este caso, una hoja de un libro `("prueba5.xlsx")` a una hoja de un libro diferente `("Hoja15.xlsx")`  [Copy worksheet from one workbook to another one using Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344041/copy-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another-one-using-openpyxl) siento decir que directamente `openpyxl` no cuenta con dicha característica. No obstante he respondido la pregunta considerando que todas las operaciones son en el mismo libro: `("prueba5.xlsx")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El asunto está que cuando se quiere copiar una hoja entera tal como ésta, a otra, no es necesario crear la hoja destino.

Dicho de otra manera, bastaría duplicar la existente y sólo cambiarle el nombre.

También existe una function `miLibroAbierto.sheetnames` para identificar qué hojas contiene `miLibroAbierto` y así evitar en la medida de lo posible llamarlas mediante el `active`, ya que puede resultar un poco confuso si el libro abierto contiene muchas hojas.

Por lo expuesto el código sería así

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

libro2 = "prueba5.xlsx"
workbook2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(libro2)

# En este caso la hoja ORIGEN corresponde a la hoja
# inicial de libro2 por defecto en mi caso es Hoja1
# aunque python la denomina en inglés: sheet
# ESTO ES OPCIONAL si ya la hoja tiene el NOMBRE ORIGEN
workbook2.active.title = 'ORIGEN'

# Revisar los nombres de las hojas
# contenidas en el libro2
# en este caso sólo existe una hoja: ORIGEN
print(workbook2.sheetnames)
# Se imprime en este caso: ['ORIGEN']

# Se define una variable para 
# la hoja ORIGEN 
# a fin de no emplear "active"
origen = workbook2['ORIGEN']

# Se copian los valores de la
# hoja ORIGEN a la destino
# esta función también crea la hoja en cuestión
destino = workbook2.copy_worksheet(origen)

# Se le pone el nombre "DESTINO"
# de lo contrario python lo define
# como ORIGEN Copy
destino.title= 'DESTINO' 

# Se guarda
workbook2.save(libro2)
```

El Resultado, es copiado con los formatos de colores de la celda, de número, moneda y/o fechas y las fórmulas también:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## **CONSIDERACIONES:**

Cuando se emplea el método `copy_worksheet` la página 16, capítulo 7 de [*openpyxl Documentation*](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/ssopenpyxl/2.5.0-b1/ssopenpyxl.pdf) indica lo siguiente:

> ***Note:*** Only cells (including values, styles, hyperlinks and comments) and certain worksheet attribues (including dimensions, format and properties) are copied. All other workbook / worksheet attributes are not copied - e.g. Images, Charts.

Traducido:

> ***Nota:*** Sólo celdas (incluye valores, estilos, hipervínculos y comentarios) y ciertos atributos del libro (incluye dimensiones, formato y propiedades) son copiadas. Los demás atributos del libro / hoja no son copiados - ejemplo Imágenes y Gráficas

No obstante si se habla de gráficas *-charts-*, (excepto diagramas y demás elementos como cuadros de texto, flechas, etc.) si podría haber una solución pero ya no correspondería a la pregunta inicial.

Esta solución implicaría crear las gráficas desde `openpyxl` [charts](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/introduction.html) esto sería posible teóricamente, porque se tiene la misma data en las mismas posiciones de las celdas,... sería llamar a estas funciones para que se creen también las gráficas *-charts-* en la hoja duplicada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya agregue esto a mi código y funciona excelente.

Comment: Hola, que pena molestarte otra vez, pero tuve un problema en las hojas que contienen imágenes,  pues la omite, sabes alguna forma de incluir las imágenes (?)

Comment: Ya veo, gracias por la ayuda.!