# Verificar si una worksheet existe en un documento de Excel usando openpyxl

Tags: excel, bucles, python-3.7

Quisiera ver si existe una forma directa de ver si existe una worksheet
"Hoja1" en un documento cualquiera, actualmente listó las worksheet
y hago un recorrido de la lista en busca de "Hoja1" pero si existe una forma directa de hacerlo, quisiera saberla, ¡Gracias!.

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor @ArnoldValencia es recomendable que se sigan las pasos contenidos en [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el riesgo de que mi pregunta obtenga puntaje negativo, voy a responder esta vez porque el **OP** ya proporcionó un ejemplo en esta pregunta: [Duplicar una hoja de excel con openpyxl en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244430/duplicar-una-hoja-de-excel-con-openpyxl-en-python)

Si se abre el fichero de excel `"prueba5.xlsx"` con `openpyxl` y se almacena en una variable: `workbook2`, se puede emplear el método `sheetnames` sobre ella para que arroje una lista, qué de acuerdo a lo posteado, supongo se está usando un bucle `for` o similar para indexarla.

Adicionalmente si se tienen las hojas `ORIGEN` y `DESTINO` en el fichero `prueba5.xlsx` y se quiere verificar que la hoja `DESTINO` existe en el citado fichero se puede emplear: **`in`** dentro de un: **`if`** para qué, de ser cierta, se haga algo.

El código quedaría así:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

libro2 = "prueba5.xlsx"
workbook2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(libro2)

#
# RESTO DEL CODIGO
#

print(workbook2.sheetnames)
#['ORIGEN', 'DESTINO']

print('DESTINO' in workbook2.sheetnames)
# TRUE

if 'DESTINO' in workbook2.sheetnames:
    # "HACER ALGO"
```

La línea `if 'DESTINO' in workbook2.sheetnames: # "HACER ALGO"` verificar rápidamente si la hoja de interés está contenida en el fichero `prueba5.xlsx` sin necesidad de emplear un `bucle`.

Comment: Ya agregue esto a mi código y funciono perfecto.¡Gracias!